# What if you put @x = 5 right after class definition?

Tags: ruby, variables

1) What is the role of @x in this code? Its not an instance variable right? Because there was no attr_accessor , or initialize method in my code. (if i remember correctly)

2) How can I view the data in x? How can I reach that?

Here is the code:

```
class A
@x = 5
// some other things here
end
```

Comment: It's an instance variable of the class object.

Comment: But I thought class variables must be shown like @@x = 5. Whats the difference between them?

Comment: Class variables are accessible easily also in subclasses (i.e. if you define `@@a = 5` in parent class, this value will be the same in sublass) and instances of the class.

Comment: "class variables" is not the same thing as "instance variable on the class object". Very different, in fact.

Comment: I never use `@@x` but sometimes `@x`. However in general I try and avoid any state in classes as it is global and can't easily be changed for different contexts.

Answer (score 5):

A class object itself is an instance of `Class`.

```
A.class
#=> Class
```

So this is indeed an instance variable, just on the class `A` itself, not on instances of `A`. Without an accessor you get the value like this:

```
A.instance_variable_get('@x')
#=> 5
```

The difference between class variables (`@@x`) and class instance variables (`@x`) is that the former are shared with subclasses, whereas the latter are not:

```
class Test1 ; @@x = 5 ; end
class Test2 < Test1 ; end

Test2.class_variable_get('@@x')
#=> 5
Test1.class_variable_set('@@x', 1)
#=> 1
>> Test2.class_variable_get('@@x')
#=> 1
```

This does not happen with class instance variables:

```
class Test3 ; @x = 5 ; end
class Test4 < Test 3 ; end

Test3.instance_variables
#=> [:@x]
>> Test4.instance_variables
#=> []
```

Comment: I'd say that is the main difference, yes. But not the only one. For example, class variables provide what I call "unambiguous access": If you use `@@x`, you'll always refer to the class variables, from everywhere (instance context or class context).

Comment: I'd say instance variables are pretty unambiguous, people just tend to get confused as to what the `self` they are currently operating on is (though except for rare meta programming cases I think it's generally rather obvious).

Comment: Not obvious, no. I mean, for well factored/structured code it is. But imagine a method `foo` defined in the middle of 200-LOC `class << self` block. And you arrive to its definition from project search results. (_this may have happened to me more times that I'd like_)

Comment: Now this is getting a bit off-topic, but if you have 200 LOC `class << self` blocks, ambiguous instance variables don't strike me as the biggest problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an instance variable for objects of class A, but it *is* an instance variable for the class itself.  A class is just an object in ruby, so that class can have its own instance variables.

```
class A
  @x = 5
  def self.show_my_var
    @x
  end
end

A.show_my_var
=> 5
```

Comment: But I thought class variables must be shown like @@x = 5. Whats the difference between them?

Comment: Who said anything about class variables?